# Remove possibility to trigger a button with a keyboard input

Tags: c#, button, input, keyboard, click

I have a standard button, with nothing interesting in it, and everything works perfectly:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Whatever, is not important what's in it
}
```

The problem is, when I click on a button, if after that I press for example enter key or the space key, it will trigger the button as if I clicked it.

I tried messing with the properties and is no help either.
How do I prevent that from happening in a (possibly) easy way?

Answer for anyone who needs it(to put inside the button):

```
if (e is MouseEventArgs)
{
     //what you want in for the button to do
}
```

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: @Roma it's WinForms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the type of the given `EventArgs`, if the button is clicked `e` is a `MouseEventArgs` (and will contain info about the click), otherwise is just a `EventArgs`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (e is MouseEventArgs)
    {
        // Is mouse click
    }
    else
    {
        // Not mouse click...
    }
}
```

Comment: But here is redundant call of event handler.

Comment: @Roma I'm not calling any method

Comment: But when ENTER is pressed this event handler do some work. You can disable tabbing of the button and this button won't trigger this event handler

Comment: @Roma i have just single operations in it, i don't think i'll have any problem.

Comment: @JackIta,  it is not a problem, this solution will work as you expect. this solution will be even better to handle mouse and keyboard click in different ways. But in your case the keyboard is ignored. If this solution works for you that's great)

Answer (score 0):

Although Matteo Umili has provided an effective solution I thought I would share this solution in case anyone finds it useful:

Simply remove the focus away from the button to another control. This solution requires another control for the focus to switch to. In my example, I am using a label.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Focus();
    }
```